# How to disable UINavigation swipe pop gesture only for UITabbarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working on iOS application and I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.3.

I have to enable swipe gesture to pop `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController` and this is my application screen flow:

[image]

Flow description:

- I am using `UINavigationController` and splash screen is on `rootViewController`.
- After 3 seconds on splash screen I am pushing screen where user can register and login.
- After login or register I am pushing `UITabbarController`.
- There are four tab bars in `tabBarController` and each contain `navigationController`.
- To open cart screen I am also pushing it from `UITabbarController`.
- After cart screen I am pushing Payment Screen.

I am using following code to enable screen pop using swipe gesture.
I have added this line in Splash screen:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil

}
```

This swipe gesture navigation pop is working fine but I just want to disable it only for tab bar controller. When I was swiping left to tab controller it is pop the screen on which we are showing "Login" and "Signup" button.

So my issue is how to disable swipe gesture pop for some screen in navigation stack.

Comment: `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the 'interactivePopGestureRecognizer' in your desired VC for not making that swipe-able add this snippet in viewDidLoad

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

And if you want to enable in other VC make sure to enable it by using -

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```

Give it a try!